# Undefined helpers fail silently

Tags: meteor

When i use something that is undefined in my templates I'd like to have it log an error instead of failing silently.  is there a way?

I just spent 20 minutes trying to figure out why my helper wasn't being called and it was defined on the wrong template.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but I believe the reason for this behavior is that it would also cause errors when particular fields aren't found on the data context, as they are declared the same way in the template HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I use global helpers instead. Templates are accessible from the command line so that's why I end up doing this anyway. If I need custom helpers for a template I define them with Iron-Router on the `data` object of the route.

Also, to ease this behavior you could make a helper for your app (as in `App.helper.return`),  containing, say `_.isUndefined(helperReturnValue)`, to throw an error. But then of course, this is not that convenient for production unless you, somehow, set client-side the `process.env.node_env` variable of your server.